# classloader issues with hibernate and groovyConsole

Tags: hibernate, groovy, groovy-grape

I am trying the example code for using hibernate in Groovy here:

[Using Hibernate with Groovy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321201118/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Hibernate+with+Groovy)

It works fine when I run it via groovy, but when I run it with groovyConsole I am getting a classloader issue:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken
```

A little googling suggest to me that the issue is Hibernate and ANTLR coming from different classloaders, but if that is the case, it isn't clear to me how I might work around the issue and still use grape for dependencies. (I have several developers who are very productive with the console, and I would really like to avoid retooling.)

Comment: Does using `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)` help?

Comment: When I add that I get

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`

which seems even weirder to me. Still works fine when run via groovy.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is this comment that I had overlooked

`// javax.transaction jta.jar added manually to ivy repo`

I am running a completely vanilla grapes config.